# Turn API's Int property into a String

Tags: swift

Sorry for the title's poorly phrased question. I'm still trying to get the hang of how programmers talk.

So basically the API that I am working with has a property (let's call it Car) that has the following structure:

```
struct Car: Codable {
    var Color: String
    var Brand: Int
    
}
```

According to the documentation,

> Car.Brand = 1 equals to Ford,
>
> Car.Brand = 2 equals to Honda,
>
> and Car.Brand = 3 equals to Toyota

How can I implement this struct in my code so that, if I wanted to get an array of Car Brands I would get

["Ford", "Honda", "Toyota"] instead of [1, 2, 3]?

I tried making an enum like so:

```
enum Car: Int, CaseIterable {
    case 1 = "Ford"
    case 2 = "Honda"
    case 3 = "Toyota"
}
```

but I found out that I can't get an enum with cases that are integers.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Off the top of my head, something like `case ford = 1` should work. Make the enum codable & conform the `Brand` variable to `car`

Comment: A possible other solution: `enum Car: Int { case 1, 2, 3 , var name: String { switch self { case 1: return "Ford"; case 2: return "Honda"; etc. }}}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mixed up the sides of the enum `Car`. A valid enum with an Int raw value should look like this:

```
enum Brand: Int, CaseIterable, Codable {
    case ford = 1
    case honda = 2
    case toyota = 3
}
```

(I have also named the enum `Brand`, because it fits better.)

In your codable model you can also use `Brand` directly.

```
struct Car: Codable {
    var Color: String
    var Brand: Brand
}
```

If you need `Brand` later as a string, you can also extend the enum with an extension:

```
extension Brand {
    var name: String {
        switch self {
        case .ford: return "Ford"
        case .honda: return "Honda"
        case .toyota: return "Toyota"
        }
    }
}
```